# Cannot install Windows 10 1511 10586 update - Intel Iris Graphics 5100 not compatible

Tags: windows-10, drivers, graphics-card, windows-update

I have Mac Mini with Windows 10 in Boot Camp.

Windows 10 Update to version 1511 10586 fails with error:

> This device isn't compatible in windows 10. Contact the manufacturer
>   for more info.
>
> - Intel Iris Graphics 5100 (Intel Corporation)

[image]

I tried following:

- Reinstalling [Windows support software (drivers)](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT204923) - update failed
- Reinstall only graphic card driver to original provided by Apple in above step - that installed older driver than I already had - update failed
- Hiding all (driver) updates with [Microsoft "Show or hide updates troubleshooter"](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/3073930) - update failed

Comment: @Ramhound Do you know that for fact or just assuming? I am asking because some people tried installing drivers from Intel site and it didn't work. However that was about month ago, so things might have changed in the meantime. I just couldn't deal with the update issue sooner.

Comment: @Ramhound At some point after I rolled back drivers to older drivers provided by Apple (Intel) Windows Update found newer drivers and updated them. And even after that 1511 update failed. So I assumed I had the latest drivers...  I have this problem for last three months... one would think that this was enough time for both MS and Intel to provide proper solution without users having to hack around in any way.

Comment: @Ramhound Thanks, I'll keep that in mind for the future.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After doing following I successfully installed Windows 10 update to version 1511 10586

1. Hide all updates except Windows 10 1511 10586 update with help of [Microsoft "Show or hide updates troubleshooter"](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/3073930)
2. Open `Control Panel` -> `Device Manager` -> Uninstall existing graphic cards driver
   [image]
3. Do not restart Windows after driver is uninstalled
4. Open `Settings` -> `Updates & Security` -> and proceed with updating